# React.createContext throwing error when using Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use React contexts to manage my states throughout child components in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript). However, I currently face an issue with the following code:

Inside `contexts/context.ts` I have:

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext(null);
```

Inside `components/Parent.tsx` I have:

```
import {MyContext} from '../contexts/context';

export default function Parent() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

    const MyContextManager = React.useContext(MyContext);

    return (
       <MyContextManager.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
          <Child />
       </MyContextManager.Provider>
    )  
 }
```

And inside my Child component I have:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useContext(MyContext);

const handleState = (value) => {
      setState(value);
}
```

However, I currently get an error:

```
TypeError: MyContextManager is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to use `MyContext.Provider`. Check [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Also you mentioned using TypeScript, yet that TypeError is a runtime error. It seems like TS thinks your `MyContextManager` is of type `any` or so. *That, or TypeScript thinks having `null` as a component type is fine.*